# Are continuous functions of compact support a dense subspaces of $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Lately, I have been studying Hilbert spaces. I want to know how to prove that continuos functions of compact support are dense subspaces of $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$?

Comment: do it in stages: first, characteristic functions can be approxmated by continuous functions w/compact support: use regularity of the measure and Urysohn Lemma (or a construction from scratch). Then extend the result to simple functions and from there to $\mathscr L^p$ -functions.

Comment: It reduces to showing that the continuous functions are dense in $L^2$, i.e.  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \|f-f \ast \phi_\epsilon \|_{L^2} = 0$ where $f \in L^2$ and $\phi_\epsilon$ is a sequence of continuous and compactly supported functions approximating the identity of the convolution